# Increase the linewidth of a MeshLinePlot in Kivy?

Tags: kivy

Does anyone know how to increase the linewidth of a MeshLinePlot in Kivy?

Thank you

## Update

I got the answer from @Ikolim to work modifying the LinePLot function from kivy.graph

```
class LinePlot(Plot):
'''LinePlot draws using a standard Line object.
'''

'''Args:
line_width (float) - the width of the graph line
'''

def __init__(self, line_width=1, **kwargs):
    self._line_width = line_width  # instead of kwargs.get('line_width', 1)
    super(LinePlot, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on the method __init__ for Kivy garden.graph at [https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.graph/blob/master/**init**.py](https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.graph/blob/master/__init__.py), MeshLinePlot currently does not support line width. But LinePlot do support line width.

## snippet

```
    self.plot = LinePlot(line_width=4, color=[1, 0, 0, 1])
```

## Example

### main.py

```
import kivy
kivy.require("1.10.0")

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

from kivy.garden.graph import Graph, MeshLinePlot, MeshStemPlot, LinePlot, SmoothLinePlot, ContourPlot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivyagg import FigureCanvas
from kivy.utils import get_color_from_hex as rgb
from numpy import sin


kv = """
<GraphCustom>:

<Test>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    GraphCustom:
        size: self.parent.size
        pos: self.parent.pos
"""

Builder.load_string(kv)


class GraphCustom(Graph):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(GraphCustom, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.label_options = {'color': rgb('#FF0000'), 'bold': True}
        self.background_color = rgb('f8f8f2')
        self.tick_color = rgb('808080')
        self.border_color = rgb('808080')
        self.xlabel = 'X'
        self.ylabel = 'Y'
        self.x_ticks_minor = 5
        self.x_ticks_major = 25
        self.y_ticks_major = 1
        self.y_grid_label = True
        self.x_grid_label = True
        self.padding = 5
        self.x_grid = True
        self.y_grid = True
        self.xmin = -0
        self.xmax = 100
        self.ymin = -1
        self.ymax = 1
        self.stop = False

        self.plot = LinePlot(line_width=4, color=[1, 0, 0, 1])
        self.plot.points = [(x, sin(x / 10.)) for x in range(0, 101)]
        self.add_plot(self.plot)


class Test(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Test, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        fig1 = plt.figure()
        ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)
        wid = FigureCanvas(fig1)
        self.add_widget(wid)


class TestApp(App):
    title = "Kivy Garden Graph - LinePlot Demo"

    def build(self):
        return Test()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

### Output

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I obtained a graph using LinePlot instead of MeshLinePlot with
`self.plot = LinePlot(color=[1, 0, 0, 1])`
However, when I added the line_width parameter as  you suggested, it raised an error: super(LinePlot, self).__init__(**kwargs) TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters
Which version of kivy garden are you using? I'm using kivy.garden.graph.__version__ = 0.4-dev

Comment: I have added Python script and kv file (main.py) as an example for your reference.

Comment: Thanks for the Python script. Unfortunately, I'm still getting the same error:

`self.plot = LinePlot(line_width=4, color=[1, 0, 0, 1])
 super(LinePlot, self).__init__(**kwargs)
 super(Plot, self).__init__(**kwargs)
 TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters`

Without the line_width parameter, it works perfectly... I tried upgrading all packages but didn't solve the issue. Do you have any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: I solved the issue by modifying the LinePLot function from kivy.Graph
`class LinePlot(Plot):
    '''LinePlot draws using a standard Line object.
    '''

    '''Args:
    line_width (float) - the width of the graph line
    '''

    def __init__(self, line_width=1, **kwargs):
        self._line_width = line_width #kwargs.get('line_width', 1)
        super(LinePlot, self).__init__(**kwargs)`